# In the classic series of Doctor Who, did the UNIT HQ building have a name?

Tags: doctor-who

As the title asks, in the classic series of Doctor Who, did the UNIT HQ building have a name?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, UNIT's headquarters buildings have never had names; there's never been any signage identifying them as anything other than "UNIT headquarters":

[image]

Even in modern Who, the UNIT HQ doesn't have a name of it's own, because it's in the Tower of London.